# UITableView section from array

Tags: swift, tableview, sections

Could you help me please with TableView sections?

I have an detailsArray that contains ID and Details that belong to that id

I have another sectionArray[] with same ID as in previous array and Section names. I have no clue how in sections group by that ID.

For example:

```
if section == 0 { 
    if detailsArray[indexPath.row].id == sectionArray[indexPath.row].id 
{ header.text = *that text from proper ID*}
```

This is just simple way to explain how I'm trying to do.

Comment: Welcome to SO, I'm having a hard time understanding your question, could you try rephrasing it?

Comment: Yes, of course. So I have 2 arrays. First, I have ID: Int, Description: String. Second array, I have ID: Int(similar to First array ID) and SectionHeader: String. My problem is that I want to populate TableView Sections with Second Array which contain Id and HeaderSection. So if SectionHeader(Event 1) and it's ID = 10, I want that Section contain all information from First array with ID = 10

Comment: "First, I have ID: Int, Description: String. Second array, I have ID: Int(similar to First array ID) and SectionHeader: String" But that sounds like the problem. You have designed your model incorrectly, so it is difficult to use it to populate a sectioned table.

Comment: Do you have any idea how can I improve it or make it right?